# Access WebPage Globally with domain name(Without registering)

Tags: http, apache-http-server, ubuntu-10.10

I have an apache2 server running on an Ubuntu 10.10 server box back home. The machine serves up some documents and misc. file. I currently access it globally at `http://X.X.X.X:<portnumber>/dir/file`.

I have no interest in registering a domain name since this is something very small but is there a way that I could access it globally by entering `http://mysite:<portnumber>/dir/file`?

Would this be changed somewhere in `apache.conf` or `httpd.conf`?
Is this something that I need to add to the router to have requests for that url be associated with the IP?

I have found this on this [site](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/httpd.html), but works with a domain name you have acquired. Is there something similar I can do since I am not using port 80?

> You may also want your site to respond to www.ubunturocks.com, since
>   many users will assume the www prefix is appropriate. Use the
>   ServerAlias directive for this. You may also use wildcards in the
>   ServerAlias directive.
>
> For example, the following configuration will cause your site to
>   respond to any domain request ending in .ubunturocks.com.

```
ServerAlias *.ubunturocks.com
```

Could I just use ServerAlias `*.mysite.com:<portnumber>/dir/file`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://mysite` is not FQDN (fully qualified domain name) and wont work globally.

There are several free providers that can point a subdomain (ie `mysite.dyndns.com`) to your IP. 
[DynDNS](https://superuser.com/questions/134272/can-you-recommend-a-good-dynamic-dns-provider) are big. [Afraid.org](http://freedns.afraid.org/) offers a large selection of domain names that are easy to remember

When you have set up a FQDN that points to your IP you can use that in your conf-files instead of ubunturocks.com.

**edit:**
Your ISP should also have a hostname set to your IP. You can find it by doing a reverse lookup or visit a page like [whatsmyip.org](http://www.whatsmyip.org/more-info-about-you/). This hostname will look something like: `173-194-32-41.hsds543fsad2.ISPName.com` and may change if you have a dynamic IP.

Comment: So this cannot be accomplished without registering/paying someone?

Comment: Absolutely. Most people use it to get a hostname that is easy to remember and static even if your IP changes.